# How do I get past the space in the name of the root directory on my mtp-mount cell phone?

Tags: bash, android, mtp

I have a Motorola Droid Maxx which I can access from Thunar and the command line, but not from inside a bash script.  The problem is that the root directory on the phone appears as "Internal storage" and that space disrupts every command.

I'm using LiveWire's bash script as provided in the answer to the question "", but when I try to add in a way to get past the root into the "Internal storage" directory, I get errors such as the following:

ls: cannot access /run/user/500/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A003%2C067%5D/Internal\: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access storage: No such file or directory

As you can see (from the printed "\" in the above error), I've tried escaping the space and also quoting the name, but nothing works.

Here is a snippet from the script that tries to do this:

```
indir=$DevicePath/'Internal\\ storage'
ls $indir
```

How do I get the script to include the space in the directory name so I can ls or cd or anything into it?

Thanks!

Comment: *"As you can see"* - where? please [edit] your question to include the relevant part of your script

Answer (score 0):

Linux, in general, uses the backslash character <kbd>\</kbd> to say, in efect "flip the next character's special meaning". You want to make <kbd>space</kbd> be a regular character, rather than a delimiter, so `ls internal\ storage` will do the trick.